# Looking for a more specific Raptor engine model, that follows fuel and oxidiser flow. Anyone know where to find good Raptor resources?

Tags: spacex, reference-request, raptor

Here is our raptor inspired model in SATSIM, our virtual aerospace lab. Want to be able to model the fuel and oxidiser flow at some stage both in Blender, then WebGLbut it's trickier than it looks. Are there any resources which detail Raptor parts and functions in more detail?  Keen to know more. Going to build a more detailed breakdown of each component, with mini tutorials on each component and its function if people are interested in it.

[image]

Comment: That will be quite hard, as the Raptor is still very much under development and improvement, the detail of the Raptor plumbing and wiring changes on an almost weekly basis (judging from the photos of the raptor on here: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=53555.0 ), not to mention the structure around them as they are installed, like the recently-added aero? shields around the outer ring of Raptors on the superheavy booster. Also *which* Raptor? The 200-ton test units on STarship? The 230-ton nongimballed ones? Raptor vac? Raptor2?

Comment: Agree with @CuteKitty_pleaseStopBArking, what you are looking for is not publicly available. Odd that you'd announce a project to "build a more detailed breakdown of each component, with mini tutorials on each component and its function" before looking into this.

Comment: SpaceX designs are their intellectual property, and what gives their company a competitive advantage, they aren't open source.

Comment: Appreciate your responses, thanks : )

Of course, I'm not looking for the REAL CAD files or schematics, its just that the full flow closed cycle engine is interesting. I personally want to know more about the theoretical components in this type of system, so it's natural to just do this sort of mock up for me, nothing helps you learn more than thinking about what goes into the assembly of the engine. So it's a Raptor "inspired" model, not the real thing!

Comment: As for announcing a project, I wanted to know if anyone was interested in it or not. All the models I see out there are basic illustrations, schematics or photorealistic 3D models, but I can't find anything that's more tutorial based. Realistically, there's no point in doing a project at that scale if no one else cares about it, I'm better off just putting my own animated model together in Blender. No upvotes so perhaps this is the wrong audience, or no one really wants it. It's all good data.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what is SATSIM?

Comment: @Ng Ph S@SIM is  a prototype of a virtual aerospace lab I'm building. 
If you want to try a demo visit here https://www.satsim.space/webmvp/survey/6.php

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried it yet but think you should include this explaination in your question. Nobody could have guessed this background to your question otherwise.